# checking all the checkboxes on the click of first checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several checkboxes on my page. If the user clicks on the first checkbox that says 1, I want all other check boxes to be checked automatically. Below is my code:

``

```
        @for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {

            <input onclick="checkAll" name="AreChecked" class="chkTask" type="checkbox" value="@i" /> @i



        }
    </div>``
```

This is the output of the checkboxes:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Cqn.png)

If the first checkbox that says 1 is checked then I want other checkboxes 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 to be checked. I don't have numbers for my checkboxes, I just have characters like, but I am displaying numbers in my code for the simplicity purposes.

This is what I tried:

`$("#1").click(function(){ $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#1").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

The if statement checks if the first checkbox is clicked - if true, then check all other checkboxes that are not the first checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimal example, you can cater it to your needs.

```js
function checkAll(event){
  var clickedElement = event.target;
  
  if (clickedElement.checked) {
    $("#1").prop("checked", true);
    $("#2").prop("checked", true);
    $("#3").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    console.log("Checkbox is unchecked");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(event)" id="1" />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(event)" id="2" />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(event)" id="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with jquery, I have done it this way

```
<input onclick="checkAll()" type="checkbox" name="test" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="">

<script>

function checkAll(){
  testcheckboxes = document.getElementsByName("test");

  testcheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.checked = true;
  });

}

</script>
```